# Java implementing a timeout to close client port after a certain time

Tags: java

I'm looking to implement both HTTP 1.0 and 1.1 spec into a Java project I'm doing.

Currently, I am able to create a socket for the server, which will accept a client socket and process the query from the client. After handling the query, the client's connection is the closed.

```
  private void start(int port) throws IOException {
      System.out.println("Starting server on port " + port);
      ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
      while(true){
        Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
        handleClientSocket(clientSocket);
      }
    }

  private void handleClientSocket(Socket client) throws IOException {
      String loc = "";
      String host = "";
      String method = "";

  BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
  String line;
  while(!(line = in.readLine()).isEmpty()){
    //Logs ouput.
    System.out.println(line); 

    ...//parse input etc.

    //form request and send it.
    HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest(loc, method, host);
    sendHttpResponse(client, formHttpResponse(request));
  }

  private void sendHttpResponse(Socket client, byte[] response) throws IOException {
  System.out.println("Writing");
  OutputStream out = client.getOutputStream();
  out.write(response);

  //close connection.
  out.close();
  }
```

This is inline with HTTP 1.0 spec as the server closes the connection once the query is completed. However, I am uncertain on how to implement HTTP 1.1 spec as it requires both persistence and pipe lining.

I have outlined what I think the flow of logic would be logic below:

1. Initialize server.
2. Wait for client connection..
3. Client sends pipelined query - multiple files.
4. Server returns requested objects.
5. Start timer if there are no additional request.
6. Check if timer has exceeded timeout, if yes close connection.

Is this an accurate representation? If so, how should I go about implementing the timeout for the port?

Comment: For your timeout, you could use `socket.setTimeout`, it will throw a `readtimeoutexception` after reading is done, but it still makes you vulnerable for slowpoke attacks

Comment: @Ferrybig There is no such method as `Socket.setTimeout()`; no such exception as `readtimeoutexception`; and read timeouts do not throw exceptions 'after reading is done'.

Comment: @OP You can't 'close client ports'. You can only close sockets. You need a good understanding of RFC 2616 and successors to implement HTTP 1.1. You're never going to get there just by asking questions here. Too broad.

Comment: @EJP there is a [`public void setSoTimeout(int timeout)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setSoTimeout(int\)) that most editors should autosuggest when you use the other method, the only thing that doesn't exist is the `readtimeoutexception`, what should have been a `SocketTimeoutException`